# Nested If Statement in Linq to SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

In SQL I would normally type this out, hard to read - yes, but it does work

```
(IIF(Table1.Field1 = 1,
    -- Field1 is True
    IIF(Table2.Field2= 1, (SUM(Table1.Field3+Table1.Field4)),(SUM(Table1.Field3+Table1.Field4)*-1))
 ,  -- Field1 is False
    IIF(Table2.Field2= 1, (SUM((Table1.Field3+Table1.Field4)*-1)), (SUM(Table1.Field3+Table1.Field4))))) AS Result
```

How would I translate this to a Linq query, I know I can do ternary, but is it possible to nest ternary?

Also my goals are to do this in one database call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write this using the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) (`?:`) like this:

```
from t in db.Table1
group t by new { t.Field1, t.Field2 } into g
select 
    g.Key.Field1 == 1 
        ? g.Key.Field2 == 1 
            ? g.Sum(t => t.Field3 + t.Field4) 
            : -g.Sum(t => t.Field3 + t.Field4) 
        : g.Key.Field2 == 1 
            ? -g.Sum(t => t.Field3 + t.Field4) 
            : g.Sum(t => t.Field3 + t.Field4)
```

But we can simplify this a bit to:

```
from t in db.Table1
group t by new { t.Field1, t.Field2 } into g
let s1 = g.Key.Field1 == 1 ? 1 : -1
let s2 = g.Key.Field2 == 1 ? 1 : -1
select s1 * s2 * g.Sum(t => t.Field3 + t.Field4)
```

Comment: Thank you, your second example is something I haven't seen done, I don't understand g.Key.Field1, was that supposed to be t.Key.Field1? I'm trying to understand what's exactly happening there lol

Comment: @JStellato I'm assuming that in the SQL there's a `GROUP BY` clause you haven't shown, so I reproduced that with `group t by ... into g`. In Linq, once you group a set variable (`t`) into another set variable (`g`), you can no longer refer to the original set variable. Hence you need to use `g.Key.Field1` to refer to `t.Field1`. However, I did just now notice a typo in how I was creating the group's key, which I have corrected.

Comment: This is very helpful to me, one last question in the group by , you have 2 fields, but I only had one field selected.  Will this result in a single field?

Comment: @JStellato `g.Key` will be whatever you provide to the `group by` clause, and using this `new { ... }` syntax is just a way to group by multiple columns simultaneously. So you can use `group t by t.Field1 into g`, then `g.Key` will be equal to `t.Field1`. You might want to check out [LINQ - Grouping Operators](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea) if you'd like to know more about how grouping in Linq queries works.